# Is it possible to show only the max / min values on a Kendo UI linear gauge?

Tags: javascript, css, kendo-ui

I currently have a linear gauge looking like this:

```
$("#depthBar-" + conveyanceId).kendoLinearGauge({
    pointer: {
        value: 0,
        shape: "arrow",
        color: "transparent",
        start: 0,
        reverse: true
    },
    scale: {
        majorUnit: 500,
        minorUnit: 100,
        min: -2000,
        max: 2000,
        vertical: false,
        reverse: false,
        ranges: [
            {
                from: -2000, // LimitLo
                to: -1500,
                color: "#ffc700"
            },
            {
                from: 2000, // LimitHi
                to: 1500,
                color: "#ffc700"
            }, {
                from: 2000, // LimitHiHi
                to: 1800,
                color: "#c20000"
            }, {
                from: -5000,
                to: -1800,
                color: "#c20000" // LimitLoLo
            }, {
                from: 0,
                to: 286,
                color: "lightblue"
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Is it possible to have the bar only display the max and min labels, and not the ones in between? In this case, I want it to only display "-2000" in one end of the scale and "2000" in the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can set the template on the scale labels as a function, do some math and only return the labels you want.

```
labels: {
             // labels template
             template: getLabel
         }
```

and

```
function getLabel(e) {
  if(e.value === 2000) {
    return 2000;
  }
  else if(e.value === -2000) {
    return -2000;
  }
  else {
    return '';
  }
}
```

Seems kind of hoky, and there is probably a better way, but that should do what I think you are wanting.  (Sample http://jsbin.com/aKAVOnE/1/edit)

Comment: Thank you for that! :D Now I'll just have to try and make it dynamic to fit all my gauges (5 of them) :)

Answer (score 1):

Setting the template will work fine. Generally when I need this done I calculate the difference between max and minimum values and set that to the major unit via parameter or in gauge creation calculation.

Answer (score 0):

set [majorUnit](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/radialgauge#configuration-scale.majorUnit) value like [max](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/radialgauge#configuration-scale.max)

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/EyoqAG)

```
$("#gauge").kendoRadialGauge({
        pointer: {
            value: $("#gauge-value").val()
        },
        scale: {
            majorUnit:180,
            minorUnit: 5,
            startAngle: -30,
            endAngle: 210,
            max: 180
        }
    });
}
```